# Android MVP - Mockito test not passing for eq(ObjectDTO), but passing for extracting values from it

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mockito, mvp

I am using Android MVP architecture and trying to resolve issue with my test.

When user click confirmation button on registration form, it should test that user was successfully created and pass the created object to View.

Here is my test(not working version):

```
   @Test
   public void clickOnConfirmButtonWithValidInput_RegisterSuccessfulCalled(){
    when(view.getEmail()).thenReturn(USER_TEST_EMAIL);
    when(view.getUsername()).thenReturn(USER_TEST_USERNAME);
    when(view.getPassword()).thenReturn(USER_TEST_PASSWORD);
    when(view.getConfirmPassword()).thenReturn(USER_TEST_PASSWORD);

    UserRegisterFormDTO userRegisterFormDTO = new UserRegisterFormDTO(USER_TEST_EMAIL, USER_TEST_USERNAME, USER_TEST_PASSWORD);

    registerPresenter.confirmRegistrationButtonClicked();

    UserDTO userDTO = new UserDTO(USER_TEST_ID, userRegisterFormDTO.getUsername(), userRegisterFormDTO.getEmail());


    verify(model).createUser(eq(userRegisterFormDTO), createNewUserCallbackArgumentCaptor.capture());
    createNewUserCallbackArgumentCaptor.getValue().onUserCreated(userDTO);

    verify(view).registerSuccessful(userDTO);
}
```

And this is the test, which is successfull.

```
@Test
public void clickOnConfirmButtonWithValidInput_RegisterSuccessfulCalled(){
    when(view.getEmail()).thenReturn(USER_TEST_EMAIL);
    when(view.getUsername()).thenReturn(USER_TEST_USERNAME);
    when(view.getPassword()).thenReturn(USER_TEST_PASSWORD);
    when(view.getConfirmPassword()).thenReturn(USER_TEST_PASSWORD);

    UserRegisterFormDTO userRegisterFormDTO = new UserRegisterFormDTO(USER_TEST_EMAIL, USER_TEST_USERNAME, USER_TEST_PASSWORD);

    registerPresenter.confirmRegistrationButtonClicked();

    UserDTO userDTO = new UserDTO(USER_TEST_ID, userRegisterFormDTO.getUsername(), userRegisterFormDTO.getEmail());


    verify(model).createUser(eq(USER_TEST_USERNAME), eq(USER_TEST_EMAIL), eq(USER_TEST_PASSWORD),  createNewUserCallbackArgumentCaptor.capture());
    createNewUserCallbackArgumentCaptor.getValue().onUserCreated(userDTO);

    verify(view).registerSuccessful(userDTO);
}
```

The Exception is like this:
https://gist.github.com/oksett/4571d09557514e6fe7ada2cc21b28d46

So I am only extract values from my UserRegisterFormDTO object and pass its values to the method as a parameter.

In my presenter i was using Model method like this:

```
@Override
public void confirmRegistrationButtonClicked() {
    if (view != null) {
        if (view.getUsername().trim().equals("") || view.getEmail().trim().equals("") || view.getPassword().trim().equals("") || view.getConfirmPassword().trim().equals("") || view.getPassword().length() < 6) {
            view.showInputError();
        } else {
            view.setRegisterProcessAlpha();
            view.showProgressBar();
            UserRegisterFormDTO userRegisterFormDTO = new UserRegisterFormDTO(view.getUsername(), view.getEmail(), view.getPassword());
            model.createUser(userRegisterFormDTO, new RegisterMVP.Model.CreateNewUserCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onUserCreated(UserDTO userDto) {
                    if (userDto != null) {
                        view.setRegisterNormalAlpha();
                        view.hideProgressBar();
                        view.registerSuccessful(userDto);
                    } else {
                        view.setRegisterNormalAlpha();
                        view.hideProgressBar();
                        view.showErrorMessage("Unfortunately user was not created, please try again");
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    }
}
```

So the test works normally for the extracting values from UserRegisterFormDTO to method as parameters. What is wrong?

UPDATE: 
Here is my UserRegisterFormDTO class:

```
public class UserRegisterFormDTO {
private String username;
private String email;
private String password;

public UserRegisterFormDTO(String username, String email, String password) {
    this.username = username;
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    UserRegisterFormDTO that = (UserRegisterFormDTO) o;

    if (!username.equals(that.username)) return false;
    if (!email.equals(that.email)) return false;
    return password.equals(that.password);

}
```

}

I implemented the equals() method, but it still not working.

Comment: Can you show us the `equals` method in the `UserRegisterFormDTO ` class please?

Comment: You need to implement it.  Otherwise, when you write `eq(userRegisterFormDTO)`, Mockito will just call the default implementation from `Object`, which is really not what you want.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I've made an edit. I automatically generated the method with my IDE(Android Studio). However, the test is still not correct

Comment: OK, what's the signature of the method you've shown in the third grey block?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I've made an edit

Comment: So where do you call the `createUser` method with the three `String` arguments?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I just refactored the method, to pass to it 3 String args instead of UserRegistrationFormDTO in this case. With this setup it is working

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem But i guess it is better to wrap String values into DTO objects between layers passing

Answer (score 0):

So this is the answer:

**I needed to implement not only equal method, but also hashCode to my UserRegistrationFormDTO**.
 Here what it looks like now:

```
public class UserRegisterFormDTO {
private String username;
private String email;
private String password;

public UserRegisterFormDTO(String username, String email, String password) {
    this.username = username;
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    UserRegisterFormDTO that = (UserRegisterFormDTO) o;

    if (username != null ? !username.equals(that.username) : that.username != null)
        return false;
    if (email != null ? !email.equals(that.email) : that.email != null) return false;
    return password != null ? password.equals(that.password) : that.password == null;

}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = username != null ? username.hashCode() : 0;
    result = 31 * result + (email != null ? email.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (password != null ? password.hashCode() : 0);
    return result;
}
```

}

The test pass now.